# extract high definition image from 1080i video with ffmpeg in linux

Tags: image, ffmpeg, jpeg, extract

I am right now using ffmpeg library to extract image from 1080i YUV 422 raw file. As i use interlaced data, it will drop some lines when i extracct image from one frame of video, Is it possible to merge two or three frame and make a single high definition image? Please guide me to move forward

Comment: Seems to me that you want to deinterlace. See the [`yadif`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#yadif-1) video deinterlace filter.

Comment: First of all tell me that am i right when i extract image from interlaced video than it will drop some lines? or ffmpeg it self manage this things?